# Ion Tabs - Load a page from a child preserving the parent's content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm facing a routing issue within an Angular application that uses Ion Tabs. My app has a "home" tab within the Ion Tabs and I want to allow navigation to a different page when a user clicks on one of the items within the "home" tab.

My routing structure is as follows:

In my "home" page, I have a list of cards and I want that when a user clicks on a card, they are redirected to a "user-trainer-view" page with a specific ID.

The "home" tab is inside Ion Tabs, but when I navigate from home to "user-trainer-view", the Ion Tabs bar disappears from view.

Here's how I'm handling navigation within my "home"

```
goToUserTrainerView(id: any) {
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs/user-trainer-view', id]);
}
```

Here are my route definitions:

In the Ion Tabs module (tabs.module.ts):

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../trainers/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomePageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'trainer-user-view/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('../trainers/user-trainer-view/user-trainer-view.module').then((m) => m.UserTrainerViewPageModule),
      }
    ],

  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'tabs/home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule { }
```

What is the problem with my routing configuration that causes the Ion Tabs bar to disappear when I navigate from the home page to the "user-trainer-view" page? How can I solve this problem and keep the Ion Tabs bar visible?

HomePage.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <!-- Header content here -->
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <div class="flexTemplate" style="overflow: scroll;">
    <h3 class="textTitle">Your subscribers</h3>

    <div #cards>
      <ion-card *ngFor="let cardData of cardDataArray"
        (click)="goToUserTrainerView(cardData.id)" class="userCard">
        <div class="pholderImg" style="margin-left: 5px;">
          <img src="{{cardData.imgUri}}">
        </div>
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title>{{cardData.username}}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
      </ion-card>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you have:

```
Initial Setup:
App
|__TabsPage
   |__HomePage
      |__Card (OnClick: Navigate to UserTrainerView with ID)
          
Navigation:
App
|__TabsPage
   |__UserTrainerViewPage (with ID, but TabsBar is missing)
```

For what I understand, when you navigate from the `HomePage` to the `UserTrainerViewPage`, you are actually *leaving* the `TabsPage` context which causes the Ion Tabs bar to disappear (when [working with tabs in ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation#working-with-tabs)).

So try and modify your `goToUserTrainerView` method to keep the `/tabs/` prefix in the path using [`navigate`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate), to make sure you remain within the `TabsPage` context.

```js
goToUserTrainerView(id: any) {
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs/trainer-user-view', id]);
}
```

Since you have defined the route for `UserTrainerViewPage` in `tabs.module.ts`, you should not need to define it again in `app-routing.module.ts`.

```js
// Remove this block from app-routing.module.ts
{
    path: 'user-trainer-view/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./trainers/user-trainer-view/user-trainer-view.module').then((m) => m.UserTrainerViewPageModule),
}
```

The recommended setup would then be:

```
App
|__TabsPage
   |__HomePage
      |__Card (OnClick: Navigate to /tabs/trainer-user-view/{ID})
   |__UserTrainerViewPage (with ID, TabsBar is visible)
```

With the updated `home.ts`:

```js
goToUserTrainerView(id: any) {
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs/trainer-user-view', id]);
}
```

And your updated `tabs.module.ts`:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../trainers/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomePageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'trainer-user-view/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('../trainers/user-trainer-view/user-trainer-view.module').then((m) => m.UserTrainerViewPageModule),
      }
    ],

  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'tabs/home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule { }
```

Again, remove the redundant route from `app-routing.module.ts`.

---

Some additional checks:

Make sure you are using an absolute path in your navigation method.

```js
goToUserTrainerView(id: any) {
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs/trainer-user-view', id]);
}
```

And also make sure your `user-trainer-view` page is being loaded within the same `<ion-router-outlet>` as your tabs page. That way, the tab bar should remain visible.

```html
<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
```

It may be helpful to look into Ionic lifecycle events to see if anything is affecting the tab bar visibility when navigating to the `user-trainer-view` page.

```js
ionViewWillEnter() {
  console.log('Page is about to enter');
}
ionViewDidEnter() {
  console.log('Page has entered');
}
```

Check if there are any CSS styles that might be hiding the tab bar.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I have the same error using your solution    idk why

Comment: @Conta OK. I have included in the answer some checks for you to consider.